# How can I use craco to modify antd LESS variables?

Tags: reactjs, less, create-react-app, antd

craco provides [this recipe](https://github.com/sharegate/craco/blob/0c35cc366ea79250e31f161172014b6a7107e3d3/recipes/use-ant-design/craco.config.js) for modifying Ant Design LESS variables with create-react-app. However, I don't understand how to modify variables through this config. The variable `lessRule` in the linked recipe has no visible effect:

```
const lessRule = {
    test: lessExtension,
    use: [
        {
            loader: require.resolve("style-loader"),
        },
        {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
        },
        {
            loader: require.resolve("less-loader"),
            options: {
                modifyVars: {
                    "@primary-color": "#1DA57A",
                    "@link-color": "#1DA57A",
                    "@border-radius-base": "2px",
                },
                javascriptEnabled: true,
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

`lessRule` is pushed to `oneOf` but I can't research what this effectively does. What do I do in this config file to see a style change manifested in the app?

Comment: It occurs to me now that I'm suffering from research fatigue surrounding problems much larger than this, but I will leave this question up on the slim chance that it *is* indeed A Good Question and of value to Stack and/or myself.

Comment: I don't understand the questions I need to ask. I'm terrified.

Answer (score 1):

[craco-antd](https://github.com/DocSpring/craco-antd) allows this. I am confused as to what the craco recipe in the question does. I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: This Q&A is vapid and almost useless but I'm not sure that's my declaration to make. Good day.